# Showing subcategory titles with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem regarding subcategories WooCommerce plugin. I want show all subcategories of main categories short by title. Please give me a suggestion regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I thing it's should help.

I'm putting all categories in a var called terms and I use query_posts according to the array in `$args`, you can change it for your subcategory need. you can use the 'order_by' property: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
    foreach ( $terms as $term )


    $args=array(
            'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
            'term' => $term->slug,
            'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ABS'
                  );

      query_posts( $args ); 
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="booklink"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile?>
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply me. But I want For WooCommerce plugin.  i able not able to find class or files which a am edit those files.